# How can I port my executable player (play.exe) for chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient

I want to port my player to chrome like flash player.
Is it have any possible solutions can do it?

I found that NaCl maybe is a solution, but It may have to redesign my player code.
So, have any way can easy port my player to chrome?

Comment: What language is your player code in?  What APIs does your player use?  What is it trying to do?  Without more information, it's pretty much impossible to give a simple answer.

Comment: My player is using C# and c++ languages. I use ffmpeg to decode video and use SDL to render it. I want to use my player to play video through chrome, like Windows Media Player plugin.

Answer (score 0):

The C# aspect might pose a bit of a problem -- you will probably need to rewrite that. However, the C++ portions and FFmpeg libraries should be portable to the NaCl framework. Pertaining to rendering, you will not be using SDL to render the video (or play audio, if that's a consideration for your application). Instead, you will be calling the interfaces that NaCl provides.

Comment: Does NaCl provides something to render video? I have no idea about that. For now, I want to build ffplay from naclports libraries. Do you think is it can try?

Comment: NaCl just provides the drawing primitives. It has no video decoding abilities the last time I checked. You would have to do the FFmpeg library porting yourself (or extract the components you need).

Comment: For my knowledge, ffplay can decode video and render video by SDL, it's produced by building ffmpeg when SDL enable. This is why I want to build ffplay. At this time, nacl has naclports project which includes many libraries, ffmpeg is included. But when I built ffplay, it has plenty of issues. So, did you know have any other way can port play (like ffplay) to chrome?

Comment: You may wish to refine your goals a bit. Do you really want to be able to play a whole universe of multimedia files? Or do you really care about playing a small subset of multimedia files?

Comment: I try it for a few weeks, and I found NaCl provides the some libraries. FFmpeg and libav are in those libraries. I can use those libraries as decoder to decode I selected video and play it by SDL. So, I modify my code from C# to C++ or C language. Finally my player can be port to google chrome.